# Passing username/password from a class and method to another class

Tags: java

I have to classes, and I need to input two values into one of the classes in my program.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class login{

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void logon() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Write your Name");
        username = System.console().readLine();
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println("Write your Password");
        password = System.console().readLine();
        System.out.println(password);

        try {
            // Does stuff
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Mainly after username and password have been verified in the try catch. I need to transfer those two strings to another class. Seen Below.

```
    public class ClientHandler {
    protected Socket client;
    protected PrintWriter out;
    protected String Username;
    protected String Password;

    public ClientHandler(Socket client) {
       //Does Stuff
    }
}
```

I would like some pointers to how I can achieve this, either through constructors, or any other method that would be efficient.

Comment: Why not pass the username / password to the constructor ?

Comment: you need [setter methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) in your `ClientHandler` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to transfer those two strings to another class.

You can do this by creating a setter method (or more than one).

You need to add these two methods to your ClientHandler class.

```
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.Password = password;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.Username = username;
}
```

Then, you set username and password variables by using these setter method

```
ClientHandler handler = ... //Create this object somehow

handler.setUsername(username);
handler.setPassword(password);
```

In your case this should go in you 'try' block